# Concatenate 2 strings from 2 different lines (From text file) - Using linecache

Tags: python, linecache

I am trying to concatenate 2 string from two different lines using linecache but when i try, the output is always on 2 lines not on 1 line.

***Text in the file:***

hello

world

***Code:***

```
import linecache
import easygui

a=linecache.getline("textfile.txt",1)
b=linecache.getline("textfile.txt",2)

easygui.msgbox (a+b)
```

***Result:***

The result(message) is: **hello world**  on two lines(on the first line is hello on the second is world)

that is not what i want, i want this: **hello world** on a single line

*Any help would be appreciated! :-)*

*P.S. Sorry for my english!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to strip the trailing newlines:

```
a = linecache.getline("textfile.txt",1).rstrip("\n")
b = linecache.getline("textfile.txt",2).rstrip("\n")
```

`str.rstrip("\n")` strips newlines from the right side of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the newline from the first string:

```
easygui.msgbox a.rstrip("\n\r") + b
```